# how to identify if ultrasonic pin is removed from circuit using python code

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

this is the simple code to measure distance using ultrasoinic sensor attached to reapberry-pi and by writing python script--

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG = 16

ECHO = 20


print "Distance Measurement In Progress"

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)

while True:

    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
    print "Waiting For Sensor To Settle"
    time.sleep(2)

    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)

    time.sleep(0.00001)

    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
       pulse_start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
       pulse_end = time.time()

    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
    distance = pulse_duration * 17150
    distance = round(distance, 2)
    print "Distance:",distance,"cm"
```

use case is- I have to run this script only when all the pins of ultrasonic sensor is properly connected to the circuit and the raspberry-pi. so my question is, can we identify the pin connection before running the script? or can we identify whether our hardware is working properly or not?

Answer (score 1):

With the trigger/echo style of interfacing, could you use a pull-up to make the echo input from the ranger be (permanently) at the 1 level when the sensor isn't fitted? In your code this line appears to be 0 during ranging and go to 1 when the echo is detected. Then the initialization code simply checks for the echo input being stuck at 1 to determine that the ranger isn't fitted. You'll need a pull-up or pull-down on that line anyway to ensure it has a valid level when the device isn't attached.

Perhaps connecting the trigger output pin to the echo input pin using a high-value (100k?) resistor (and no pullup on the echo pin) would be better - the initialization then is to waggle the trigger pin around and check for the echo pin quickly changing to the same level. If it doesn't change so quickly the ultrasonic ranger is probably attached.

A possibly more robust approach would be to use an ultrasonic sensor like the US-100 for example see http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/US-100-Ultrasonic-Sensor-Module-Temperature-Compensation-Range-for-Arduino-K6-/291843077304?hash=item43f333f4b8:g:vgkAAOSwFnFV-7Fx which has a jumper to select serial output, sent every 100ms. Using the serial interface you know if the device is/isn't fitted simply from presence/absence of data on the serial port.